# Titanium won't run iPhone/Android Emulator

Tags: android-emulator, ios-simulator, titanium, appcelerator

I just installed Titanium SDK (1.5.1) and all the Android SDKs.
Also, I already have iPhone SDK 4.2 installed.

I downloaded KitchenSink and imported it into Titanium but whenever I try to run it on iPhone Emulator, I get this error:

```
[INFO] One moment, building ...
[INFO] Titanium SDK version: 1.5.1
[INFO] iPhone Device family: iphone
[INFO] iPhone SDK version: 4.0
[INFO] Detected compiler plugin: ti.log/0.1
[INFO] Compiler plugin loaded and working for ios
[INFO] Performing clean build
[INFO] Compiling localization files
[INFO] Detected custom font: comic_zine_ot.otf
[ERROR] Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.5.1/iphone/builder.py", line 1003, in main
execute_xcode("iphonesimulator%s" % iphone_version,["GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS=LOG__ID=%s DEPLOYTYPE=development TI_DEVELOPMENT=1 DEBUG=1 TI_VERSION=%s" % (log_id,sdk_version)],False)
File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.5.1/iphone/builder.py", line 925, in execute_xcode
output = run.run(args,False,False,o)
File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.5.1/iphone/run.py", line 31, in run
sys.exit(rc)
SystemExit: 1
```

And for Android, it runs the OS but not the KitchenSink app, here's the log:

```
[INFO] Launching Android emulator...one moment
[INFO] Building KitchenSink for Android ... one moment
[INFO] plugin=/Library/Application Support/Titanium/plugins/ti.log/0.1/plugin.py
[INFO] Detected compiler plugin: ti.log/0.1
[INFO] Compiler plugin loaded and working for android
[INFO] Titanium SDK version: 1.5.1 (12/16/10 16:25 16bbb92)
[INFO] Waiting for the Android Emulator to become available
[ERROR] Timed out waiting for android.process.acore
[INFO] Copying project resources..
[INFO] Detected tiapp.xml change, forcing full re-build...
[INFO] Compiling Javascript Resources ...
[INFO] Copying platform-specific files ...
[INFO] Compiling localization files
[INFO] Compiling Android Resources... This could take some time
```

Any ideas on how to get Titanium to work?

Comment: I have the same problem... brand new installation of OSX/Xcode and Titanium with all the newest versions, and I get the exact message that you got.

Comment: @bparker Yeah, I've seen a lot of people with the same problem, I wonder what are we doing wrong or if it's maybe a bug with this version. Really need to get this working. Maybe someone will help us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to fix it.
About the adb file, just copy or symlink it from /platform-tools to /tools and Titanium will recognize the SDK.

About the Titanium errors, here's what I did:
1 - First I downloaded the latest Titanium SDK build (1.6.0) from http://builds.appcelerator.com.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

2 - Installed it by unzipping the file's contents (a folder called 1.6.0) /Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx

3 - I then uninstalled my Xcode 1.2.5 with SDK 4.2 
NOTE: If you have other versions of Xcode installed, REMOVE them and only reinstall the latest version of it, or Titanium will not work. (At least that was the case with me)

4 - Uninstalled Titanium

5 - Reinstalled Xcode with SDK 4.2

6 - Reinstalled Titanium

7 - Open it, create or try to run an old project and it will work for both iPhone and Android.

Hope it helps.

Cheers.

Comment: I have the exact same error message as the OP (Titanium Errors when launching iphone sim). About to try your fix (xcode 3.2.5 w/ ios 4.2 sdk) although it's kind of annoying that Titanium don't test with older SDKs (I'm running 4.0) as Xcode is a 3.5 Gb download. That nails my monthly quota here in the Internet backwater of Australia. + I've already wasted half my Sunday getting past the Android SDK compatibility issues.</rant>  EDIT: Thanks for the workaround though.

Comment: Follow-up: After following your instructions, I can now build an empty project and run the iphone emulator. However I still get the same erro when trying to load KitchenSink.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same error here - really frustrating. I'm a pretty seasoned coder but Titanium has just sucked the life out of me today. Errors finding adb in the latest Android SDK so I needed to use an older SDK and now this - vanilla install - nothing wacky going on, followed their instructions perfectly but not dice. I know I haven't paid for anything yet but it still pisses me off that developers overpromise the readiness of software that obviously isn't ready for primetime.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I managed to fix my version of this issue (iPhone sim - I haven't tried Android).

First, upgrade xcode and the IOS SDK to a recent version (4.2 in my case)

Then open the projet in xcode. The file is /build/iphone/yourproj.xcodeproj

Then you will see that there is no Base SDK selected.

Select the SDK by the following menus...

XCode \ Project \ Edit Project Settings \ Build \ Base SDK - iOS Device 4.2
XCode \ Project \ Edit Active Target ‘[project name]’ \ Build \ Base SDK - iOS Simulator 4.2

Build the project in xcode (it'll probably fail)

Save and exit. Go back to Titanium and the project should now build.

Bit of a headache to get started, but there you are.